# How to return from closures in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, singleton, closures, completionhandler

I used to create a singleton class in Objective-C to execute all the service calls in my code. However, swift uses closures and I am unable to achieve the same results in Swift. Is there any way to do the same thing in Swift 3?

```
@implementation ServiceManager

+(id)sharedManager {
      static ServiceManager *sharedMyManager = nil;
      static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
      dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
          sharedMyManager = [[self alloc] init];
      });
      return sharedMyManager;
}

-(NSURLSession *)urlSession {
if (_urlSession) {
    return _urlSession;
}

NSURLSessionConfiguration *defaultConfigObject =
 [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
_urlSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:defaultConfigObject delegate:nil delegateQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];
_urlSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
_urlSession.sessionDescription = @"net.socialInvesting.nsurlsession";

return _urlSession;
}

-(void)ExecuteRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request withCompletion:(void (^)(id result, NSError *error))completionBlock {

NSURLSessionDataTask * dataTask =[[self urlSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    if(error == nil) {
        id result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
        completionBlock(result,error);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
        completionBlock(nil, error);
    }
}];
[dataTask resume];
}

@end
```

I call this function as in code snippet below.

```
[sharedServiceManager ExecuteRequest:urlRequest withCompletion:^(id result, NSError *error) {
    if (result) {
        LoginModel *model = [[LoginModel alloc]initWithDictionary:result error:NULL];
        ResponseManager *manager = [ResponseManager sharedManager];
        manager.loginResponse = model;
        completionBlock(YES,NULL);
    } else {
        completionBlock(NO,error);
    }
}];
```

This is how I tried to do similar execution in swift. But unable to return values.

```
import UIKit

class ServiceManager: UIView {

var session = URLSession.shared
static let sharedSessionManager = ServiceManager()

class func sharedManager() -> ServiceManager {
    return sharedSessionManager
}

func executeGetRequest(with urlString: String, inputDictionary:[String : Any], completionHandler: @escaping () -> (Error?, [[String : Any]])) {
    let url = URL.init(string: urlString)
    let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url!)
    let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("ERROR: could not execute request")
        } else {
            do {
                let responseDict = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String: Any]
                if let results = responseDict!["results"] as? [[String:Any]] {
                    completionHandler // How to return results and Error from here to the calling function
                }
            } catch {
                    print("ERROR: could not retrieve response")
                }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `completionHandler(nil, results)`?

Comment: In Swift this would be considered as input parameters to the completionHandler (closure). However, in the code above, I haven't mentioned any input parameters for the closure in definition.

Comment: Oops, didn't read more carefully: `@escaping () -> (Error?, [[String : Any]]))` Why it there `()` with nothing for the escaping? Did you meant `completionHandler: @escaping(Error?,[[String : Any]]?) -> Void) -> Void {`? (first Void is for the closure, the second one for the "method").

Comment: @caffieneToCode would you try with my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your help.

With some more research on closures, I achieved the result.

Below is the Singleton ServiceManager I created.

```
class ServiceManager: NSObject {

    //  Static Instance variable for Singleton
    static var sharedSessionManager = ServiceManager()

    //  Preventing initialisation from any other source.
    private init() {
    }

    //  Function to execute GET request and pass data from escaping closure
    func executeGetRequest(with urlString: String, completion: @escaping (Data?) -> ()) {

        let url = URL.init(string: urlString)
        let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url!)

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data, response, error) in
        //  Log errors (if any)
            if error != nil {
                print(error.debugDescription)
            } else {
                //  Passing the data from closure to the calling method
                completion(data)
            }
        }.resume()  // Starting the dataTask
    }

    //  Function to perform a task - Calls executeGetRequest(with urlString:) and receives data from the closure.
    func downloadMovies(from urlString: String, completion: @escaping ([Movie]) -> ()) {
        //  Calling executeGetRequest(with:)
        executeGetRequest(with: urlString) { (data) in  // Data received from closure
            do {
                //  JSON parsing
                let responseDict = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String: Any]
                if let results = responseDict!["results"] as? [[String:Any]] {
                    var movies = [Movie]()
                    for obj in results {
                        let movie = Movie(movieDict: obj)
                        movies.append(movie)
                    }
                //  Passing parsed JSON data from closure to the calling method.
                    completion(movies)
                }
            } catch {
                print("ERROR: could not retrieve response")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage Example below.

```
ServiceManager.sharedSessionManager.downloadMovies(from: urlBase) { (movies : [Movie]) in   // Object received from closure
    self.movies = movies
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
         //  Updating UI on main queue
        self.movieCollectionView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

I Hope this helps anybody looking for a similar solution.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to write `completionHandler(arg1, arg2,...)` and put the values you want to return inside the parentheses are you would when calling a function. You should change the completion handler to return optional values for both of its arguments, since if you receive an error, it is better to return a nil than an empty dictionary.

```
do {
    let responseDict = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String: Any]
    if let results = responseDict!["results"] as? [[String:Any]] {
        completionHandler(nil, responseDict)
    }
 } catch {
     completionHandler(error, nil)
 }
```

Comment: In Swift this would be considered as input parameters to the completionHandler (closure). However, in the code above, I haven't mentioned any input parameters for the closure in definition.


completionHandler: @escaping () -> (Error?, [[String : Any]]

Comment: This is how most `Swift` completion handlers are defined, including for example the completion handler of `URLSession.dataTask`, so why not do it the same way?

Comment: The definition of the dataTask method has input parameters but, here I want to send the result to the calling method. (still i would try with input parameters)
open func dataTask(with request: URLRequest, completionHandler: @escaping (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Swift.Void) -> URLSessionDataTask

Comment: The problem is, what you want to achieve is not possible. You cannot return from a closure if that closure is part of the input arguments to your function. You can make the function return  a closure, but if you supply it a closure as an input argument, that closure cannot return. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41894277/4667835)